# file_get_contents convert all special character into diamond question mark php

Tags: php, html, laravel, file

I am uploading an html document in my project and retriving the file content using file_get_contents().

But Everytime whenever some quotation or any special character appears it is been converted in to diamond shaped question mark.

Below Is my code

```
    **$path = public_path().'/upload/'.$filename.'.'.$extension;
    $striped_content = file_get_contents($path);**
```

The output of striped_content is below

```
<p class=MsoNormal align=right style='margin-top:0cm;margin-right:2.1pt;
margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:right;
line-height:10.8pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><u style='text-underline:black'>
<span lang=EN-US style='font-size:9.5pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";position:relative;top:.5pt;
mso-text-raise:-.5pt'>
<span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>�</span>
</span>
</p>
```

Above Code is simple html consist of quotation mark but it shows question mark instead..
what do i do now.

Answer (score 2):

```
The Character displayed in black diamond question mark are treated as ISO-8859-1 unicode and we are converting it into utf-8.
Below Is my Code That worked Perfectly

$path = public_path().'/upload/'.$filename.'.'.$extension;
$striped_content = file_get_contents($path);
$striped_content = mb_convert_encoding($striped_content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "ISO-8859-1");
```

I hope my answer will help anyone else too.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` does not convert anything, simple return the data from the URL.
The `�` appear to your browser because it isn't in the character set used by your browser.

Comment: 'charset' => 'utf8',                                                                               
 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',        This is my default setting

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert character encoding of your `path` to `UTF-8`.

**Try this:**

```
$path = public_path().'/upload/'.$filename.'.'.$extension;
$resolved_path = mb_convert_encoding($path, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
$striped_content = file_get_contents($resolved_path);
```

Comment: same issue.Doesn't change anything...I have tried to handle it on front end also but there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http'=>array(
    'method' => "GET",
    'header' =>  'Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0',
)));
```

$striped_content = file_get_contents($path, false, $context);

Comment: Used This Also But It has no effect

Comment: then try with mb_convert_encoding($striped_content, 'UTF-8',
          mb_detect_encoding($striped_content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));

Comment: mb_convert_encoding($striped_content, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($striped_content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));  
After Using This there is a red dot appearing instead of question mark in the  html string